# Usage of "our" in sentences where we skip that/which are

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

> We check our Facebook three times on the way to work on our smartphones more powerful than your computer.

Is this sentence correct? It sounds much better if we remove the *our* before *smartphones* but since:

> We check our Facebook three times on the way to work on big smartphones more powerful than your computer.

Is correct why should the original be wrong?

If it is wrong, what is it about *our* that makes it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here, *"our"* is a determiner, and specifically a definite determiner, while *"more powerful than your computer"* is a restrictive clause. In other words, *"more powerful than your computer"* tells you ***which*** smartphones we're checking Facebook on. If you put *"our"* in the sentence as well, you've already said which smartphones we're checking Facebook on, so you need to use a non-restrictive clause. You can do that by inserting *"that/which are"*.

Consider.

> I check Facebook three times on the way to work on a smartphone more powerful than your computer.

Here *"a"* is an indefinite determiner, so this works fine.

> *I check Facebook three times on the way to work on this smartphone more powerful than your computer.

And *"this"* is a definite determiner, so it sounds wrong.

UPDATE: In the comments, Edwin Ashworth points out that it's not the fact that *"our"* is a definite determiner that makes this sentence ungrammatical. It's the fact that *"our smartphones"* has already completely determined what we are referring to, so we can't use a restrictive clause to narrow it any further.

Comment: +1, but OP should perhaps be informed that the restrictive/nonrestrictive distinction here is entirely syntactical and has no bearing on meaning. *I check Facebook ... on* a/my *powerful smartphone*.

Comment: Does the sentence have wrong grammar or is it just bad style?

Comment: @Stilgar, yes, in case like this it is difficult to say where grammar  starts and bad style stops. By the way, Shor's answer is clear in this sense.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Is _those_ then not a definite determiner in _Not all the office computers in the office will do - I can only process such data on those computers more powerful than yours._?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All five *th-* words are definite when used as determiners.

Comment: That would seem to negate the 'rule' Peter seems to suggest about not using definite determiners with restrictive clauses. However, in the example I've come up with, _those_ + _more powerful than yours_ constitute one restriction, not two.

Comment: @Edwin: You can definitely use *the* with a restrictive clause sometimes: *"I put the tasks most in need of attention at the top of the list."* I think your example works in the same way. So my "rule" doesn't work in all instances. But I still think that the reason the sentence sounds wrong is that you can't use a restrictive clause after you've say "our smartphones", because "our smartphones" is definite enough that it can't be restricted any further.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Of course, there can be restrictions-within-restrictions: We check our Facebook three times on the way to work on those of our smartphones which are more powerful than your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It took me several minutes to realise what you are trying to say.  The grammar is irrelevant if the meaning is not clear.  What you might say is:

```
Using smartphones more powerful than a computer, we check Facebook three times
on our way to work.
```

or perhaps,

```
On our way to work, using smartphones more powerful than a computer, we check 
Facebook three times.
```

Alternatively, separate sentences might be better:

```
On our way to work, we check Facebook three times.  We use smartphones that
are more powerful than a computer
```

Note also that you are using the present tense, which implies that you do this every day or that you are describing a series of actions.  In the past:

```
On our way to work, we checked Facebook three times.  We used smartphones that are
more powerful than a computer
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your sentences is wrong but both contain unnecessary words. "Our" before smartphones is unnecessary in your first sentence because it's already implied by "*we* check Facebook"; and "big" is unnecessary in the second sentence because the Smartphone being more powerful than your computer suggests its greater size. I suggest, therefore:

> We check our Facebook three times on the way to work on smartphones
>   more powerful than your computer.

(Your probably don't need "our" before Facebook, either).